# Finding duplicate digits in integers

Tags: algorithm, search

Lets say we have an integer array of N elements which consists of integers between 0 and 10000. We need to detect the numbers including a digit more than once e.g 1245 is valid while 1214 is not. How can we do this optimally? Thanks!

Comment: Based on what you have told us the optimal approach is to scan the entire array and scan each element in the array.  What were your thoughts ?

Comment: Since we need to check every integer, yes I think we have to scan the entire array. However, I think the real problem is how to detect duplicate integers in each integer effectively.

Comment: And how do you propose to do that without looking at each digit ?

Comment: We can compare each digit with others but this will give us O(N^2) right? Is there a better solution with lower complexity?

Comment: It's not O(n^2). It's O(n * d), where `n` is the number of items in the list, and `d` is the average number of digits in each number. And, no, there is no better solution. You have to look at each digit in each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two loops.   One loop you scan each element of the array.

In the inner loop, you determine if for the given element it's valid or not based on the criteria you indicated.   To determine if a number has the same digit more than once, you need a routine that effectively extracts each digit one by one.   I think the most optimal way to do that is to do "mod 10" on the number, then loop dividing the original by 10.  keep doing that until you don't have number left (zero).  Now that you have a routine for looking at each digit of an integer, the way to determine if there are duplicate digits the most optimally is to create an array of 10 booleans.   Start with a cleared array.  For every digit, use it as an index into the bool array and set it to true.  If you see "true" again in that spot before you set it, that means that element in the bool array was visited before, thus it's a duplicate digit.  So you break out of the loop altogether and say you found an invalid value.